# Selenium installed in python, but still can't import module?

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I'm using linux mint. I installed selenium using pip, and it finished with no problems. Then I ran python and tried to check that selenium works:

```
ethomas@ethomas-linux ~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, May 19 2015, 13:47:37) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

then in python I did:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/local/bin/python'
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

I ran $ locate selenium and it's all found in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium. Yet I still can't import selenium in python. Anyone know what the problem might be? It may have something to do with the sys.path but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed python 2.7.9, while the default is 2.7.6 on my box, so it put it into usr/local/bin and was causing the error. Deleting it from usr/local/bin fixed the probelm.